# Apply function across tree nodes in Scheme

Tags: list, tree, scheme

I am using Simply Scheme in Dr. Racket.

The problem is to write tree–map, analogous to deep–map, but for trees, using datum and children selectors. This is deep-map:

```
(define (deep-map f structure)
  (cond ((word? structure) (f structure))
        ((null? structure) '())
        (else (cons (deep–map f (car structure))
                    (deep–map f (cdr structure))))))
```

This is my attempt at tree-map so far:

```
(define (tree-map f structure)
  (cond ((leaf? structure)
         (f (datum structure)))
        (else
         (cons (tree-map f (car (children structure)))
               (tree-map f (cdr (children structure)))))))
```

These are the constructors and selectors for the tree:

```
(define (make-node datum children)
  (cons datum children))

(define (datum node)
  (car node))

(define (children node)
  (cdr node))

(define (leaf datum)
  (make-node datum '()))

(define (leaf? node)
  (null? (children node)))
```

For my test case I am using this number tree with a function, eg square:

```
(define number-tree
  (make-node
   '56
   (list (make-node
          '2
          (children '(34  25 7 89)))
         (make-node
          '32
          (list (make-node
                 '27
                 (children '(13 55 80)))
                (make-node
                 '1098
                 (children '(45 785 98)))
                (make-node '123 (children '(9046)))))
         (make-node '23 (children '(1 9)))
         (make-node '867
            (children '(1 3 5 78)))
         (make-node
          '0
          (list 
           (make-node '78 (children '(984)))
           (make-node '45
              (children '(23 46 78467)))
           (make-node '3 (children '(2))))))))
```

The error messages I get are things like 'cdr, contract violation, expected pair.' I have not had too much problem working with lists in Scheme so far - I seem to get them. But translating to trees is causing me a problem - there's something I don't get in principle which means I keep getting these list related error messages on tree problems. I am trying to keep to using the abstract type (the tree and nodes) without thinking about lists. 
Am I going about this in the right way? Any help in understanding what I am missing to work well with trees is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure called `children` is an accessor, not a constructor. Thus this:

```
(make-node
          2
          (children '(34  25 7 89))
```

Should have been:

```
(make-node 2
           (list (leaf 34)
                 (leaf 25)
                 (leaf 7)
                 (leaf 89)))
```

You could do as in the book and have a way to make leafs, perhaps like this:

```
(define (leafs lst-values)
  (map leaf lst-values))

(make-node 2 (leafs '(34  25 7 89)))
```

Your tree nodes that aren't leafs have values, like 2 in my node example, while general tree structure a leaf is anything except a pair and a pair is a node with two children. Here is a `tree-map` that works on the trees made by `make-node`:

```
(define (tree-map proc tree)
  (let aux ((tree tree))
    (make-node (proc (datum tree))
               (map aux (children tree)))))
```

Notice that for a `leaf` node `(children tree)` would be `'()` and `(map anything '())` always becomes '() so that the `make-node` would make a new leaf. The recursion is via map since this tree has multiple children while tree structure only have two. Because of the strict structure the values of this tree can be pairs as well.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. Tree-map did work. It is good to understand the mistake I made with the number-tree.